# Como realizar relleno a un poligono utilizando MouseListener y MouseMotionListener

Tags: java

tengo un problema con este código en el cual debo crear un polígono, en este caso he creado algo así como un rectángulo, y en el por medio de MouseListener y MouseMotionListener al ejecutar el programa y darle click al polígono este se rellene de color.

este es el código que utilice para crear el polígono, pero respecto a llenar el polígono, no he descubierto la forma de hacerlo

```
package polipoli;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DibuPoli extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

public void paint(Graphics g) {
  int[] xs = {125, 75, 125, 185, 125};
  int[] ys = {125, 75, 50, 100, 125};
  g.drawPolyline(xs, ys, 5);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {    
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Esta es como la segunda vez que realizo una pregunta por aquí, y espero que este bien formulado lo que necesito resolver.
Gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigo lo que necesitas hacer es que en el método mouse clicked tienes que obtener las coordenadas de donde presionaste simplemente asignando los valores obtenidos por **me.getX()** y **me.getY()** a una variable en el metodo, para validar si fue dentro de la figura, en caso de que sea así solo necesitas pintar la figura de nuevo pero esta vez ponerla como **g.fillPolygon(xs,ys,5)** y llamar al metodo **repaint()**, para esto la variable grafica **g** así como las variables **xs** e **ys** deben ser declaradas globalmente